# Unpacking an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterable-unpacking

I have a variable data that is of `(1000L, 3L)` shape and I do the following to get the coordinates:

```
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]
```

Is there a way to unpack them? I tried but it doesn't work:

```
[x,y,z] = data1[:,0:3]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could simply [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) it before unpacking:

```
x, y, z = data.T
```

Unpacking "unpacks" the first dimensions of an array and by transposing the your array the size-3 dimension will be the first dimension. That's why it didn't work with `[x, y, z] = data1[:, 0:3]` because that tried to unpack 1000 values into 3 variables.

Answer (score 3):

You could unpack using `zip`:

```
x, y, z = zip(*data[:, :3])
```