# r,g,b=data[i].T what does it mean?

Tags: python, numpy

```
def plot_pixels(data,title,colors=None,N=10000):
    if colors is None:
        colors=data
    rng=np.random.RandomState(0)
    i=rng.permutation(data.shape[0])[:N]
    print(len(i))
    colors=colors[i]
    r,g,b=data[i].T
    print(len(r),len(g),len(b))
    print(r,g,b)
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(16,6))
    ax[0].scatter(r,g,color=colors,marker='.')
    ax[0].set(xlabel='Red',ylabel='Green',xlim=(0,1),ylim=(0,1))
    ax[1].scatter(r,b,color=colors,marker='.')
    ax[1].set(xlabel='Red',ylabel='Blue',xlim=(0,1),ylim=(0,1))
    fig.suptitle(title,size=20)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpacking an array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133444/unpacking-an-array-in-python)

Comment: That goes by the name of "tuple unpacking". Google knows a lot about them. It is done also here `fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(16,6))` in the code you show.

Comment: Image arrays often have a (n,m,3) shape. The `.T` does a transpose, making a(3,m,n) shape.  Unpacking then splits that array into 3 (m,n) shaped ones.